# Shortest Substring that has the maximum difference in counts of A and B

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I encountered a problem that asked to find the shortest substring from the left that has the maximum difference in the counts of its characters. We are guaranteed that the string contains just two characters, say 'A' and 'B'. We need to find the shortest and leftmost substring such that the absolute difference between the counts of 'A' and 'B' in this substring is maximized.

An example would be "BAABAABAABB". In this case the substring would be "AABAABAA", substring starting at index 1 and ending at 8, because count of A is 6 and B is 2, the difference is 4. So, the answer would be 
(1, 8), i.e. the starting and ending indices of the substring.

I wrote an algorithm in Python that can do this in the following way.

```
max_diff = 0

def calc(word):
    return abs(word.count('A') - word.count('B'))      

def get_window(word):
    if len(word) == 1:
        return (0, 0)
    for start in range(len(word)-1):
        for end in range(start+1, len(word)):
            diff =calc(word[start:end+1])
            if diff == max_diff:
                return (start, end)

word = "BAABAABAABB"
for start in range(len(word)-1):
    for end in range(start+1, len(word)):
        max_diff = max(max_diff, calc(word[start:end+1]))
print get_window(word)
```

I think the time complexity of this solution is O(N^3).
How would I go about improving the efficiency of this program? There might be more efficient and faster approaches to this problem. Any help improving the efficiency and coming up with an improved algorithm would be very helpful. Thank You!

Comment: Given the choice between a shorter substring that's further to the right, vs. a longer substring that's further to the left, which is considered preferable?

Comment: Always choose the shortest substring. If two substrings of the same length are available whose difference is the max difference, choose the leftmost substring.

Answer (score 1):

It should work about this way:

Create second array which represents numbers "between" the characters, counting up one for, say, A and counting down one for B. For the example this array would look like

```
 0 -1  0  1  0  1  2  1  2  3  2  1 
  B  A  A  B  A  A  B  A  A  B  B
```

During building of the array remember the place(s) where the values are minimal and maximal. If there are multiple maximum or minimum points the task is now reduced to find a maximum and minimum point which are nearest together.

**Why does this work?**

It is easy to see that the result of your `calc(word)` is always the same as the absolute difference of the array numbers "enclosing" this `word`. Example: For "ABA" `calc()` will return 1 and if you look at the enclosing numbers for the two occurrences of "ABA", they are 0 and 1 (result 1) and 1 and 2 (also result 1).

So the largest possible value of `calc()` for a given string (which is the desired maximum difference value) is the absolute difference of extreme values of the array numbers which can only appear when array indices with these extreme values are used to "enclose" the substring.

**Finding shortest extreme value distance**

Assuming the maximum and minimum points are now contained in two ordered lists `l1` and `l2` (from smallest to largest index number) the further algorithm is as follows:

- (Loop start)
- Ensure that `l1[0] < l2[0]`, otherwise swap `l1` and `l2`
- Remember `(l1[0], l2[0], l2[0] - l1[0])` as possible result candidate
  if you hadn't encountered a better candidate before.
- Remove first element from `l1`. If `l1` is empty now end loop.
- Go back to loop start.

Comment: Interesting. Could you please explain how you came up with this approach? Ans also could you please explain why this approach would always work?

Comment: @therealdev The sequence of A and B looked somehow like the description of a function going up and down, I can't really explain why I saw it this way. An explanation why it works is now added to the answer.